# Data Driving Open-Source SoapUI REST Requests

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui, data-driven-tests

I am currently using SoapUI 5.0.0 and want to be able to change my parameters for all of my REST request calls using a single file, saving me from changing them from each test.

Now it appears SoapUI Pro has a feature called "Data Source" but there is nothing to help with this in the free version of SoapUI?

I have placed a sample of the values passed in the request and the XML response I get back.

**Passed Values**

- `postcode`: `XX XXX`
- `productlist`: `123456`

**XML response**

```
<postcode>LS11 0EY</postcode>
   <products>
      <e>
         <localStockCount>309.0</localStockCount>
         <productKey>10006541</productKey>
         <stockUnitOfMeasure>LN</stockUnitOfMeasure>
```

How can I data drive the `postcode` and `productlist` passed in the request using the free version of SoapUI?

Comment: So.... purchase the Pro version? Also, your XML is not well-formed.

Comment: Does not help in any way? but thanks for the comment.

Comment: So I can fine tune my answer if appropriate, do you **a)** want to *loop* through different sets of `productcode` and `productlist` values in a text file, submitting one or more requests based on each set of values, or do you **b)** just want to change `postcode` and `productlist` values in one place, affecting one or more requests?  SoapUI custom properties, which I called out in my preliminary answer, are key to either scenario; but as my answer now stands, it is better suited to scenario **b)** than scenario **a)**.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your feedback I have been busy with some other work. I will attempt this tonight using the feedback below but to summarise what I am trying to do: (1) Be able to pass my REST request values which are postcode and productlist via an excel file and not via the REST fields in soapui. (2) No i don't want a loop as within each test file I have different test cases which test different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SoapUI custom properties](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html) to parameterize your requests.

Consider the following REST request as an example:

[image: SoapUI REST Request Parameterized with Custom Properties]

When the request is submitted, SoapUI will substitute (or "expand") the property placeholder `${#Project#timeZoneDbKey}` in the request parameter's Value, replacing it with the property's configured value (i.e. `BlahBlahBlah` in this case).

The project-level custom property `timeZoneDbKey` is defined in the project's Custom Properties tab:

[image: SoapUI REST Project with Custom Properties]

In your case, it sounds like you would need similar `postcode` and `productlist` custom properties.

If you like, you can export a project's custom properties to a text file...

[image: Saving a SoapUI REST Project's Custom Properties to a Text File]

..., but they are saved within the project file's XML itself: so this is redundant.